# Using keyof in Typescript to get rid of 'element implicitly has any type' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know this has other questions on it but none of them seem to be helping me understand what I need to do to fix this.

I have an attribute that I have set as part of my Component's state, and this object is **supposed to be** an object that I'm using as a "map" to store key-value pairs.

```
SampleAttribute: {
  x: '',
  y: []
}
```

The value for it is set in one of my component's functions, where I use this.setState to set the attribute to an object I initialized as follows:

```
    let kvPairs: { [key: string]: any[] } = {};
```

However, at some point before my function calls this.setState, it stores this.state.SampleAttribute in a variable `sampleAttribute`. At this point, I want to check if a string array `listOfThings` has any of its elements as a key of sampleAttribute, so I am calling

```
listOfThings.map(thing => {
  if (sampleAttribute[thing])
    // do stuff
})
```

It is at the line in the if statement that I get the error:

```
TypeScript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

I understand many of the answers require using keyof to let the compiler know what it can accept as strings to index the object, but it seems doing that requires me creating a new type, since keyof requires a Type passed to it...so I'm just confused as to how I can do this without going that route.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a typesafe accessor like this:

```
const doOnIndex = <T>(obj: T, thing: string, fn: (ele: typeof obj[keyof typeof obj]) => void): void => {
  if (thing in obj) {
    fn(obj[thing]);
  }
};

// Used like
doOnIndex(SampleAttribute, thing, ele => ele);
```

In this case you are telling the compiler that because you successfully indexed your object, the resulting type must be the union of the types of the values of the known object.

I'm not sure why kvPairs is relevant, it would be a *lot* easier to follow with a full code example.

Comment: I know people say to post the whole full code but this is a class from my job that's over 300 lines long. I would never post all of it and I don't know how I can tell what's useful or not to exclude

Comment: Why does an answer for what feels like should be something simple look so complex? Like am I writing code that's so contrary to how react should be used that I can't find a single example in SO that's similar and just works?

Comment: The error you are encountering is only being raised because you have enabled the noImplicitAny option of TS. In fact, you could simply ignore it (with an `// @ts-ignore`) and your program would work fine. If you really can't have implicit `any`s AND you have to dynamically index an object, you are going to have to tell TS how to handle that.